# Add link to parent page in list of child pages

Tags: child-pages

I try to add link to parent page to a working list of childpages. The parent page must be the first item's list whenever the list appear.

Here is the actual code found [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-a-list-of-child-pages-for-a-parent-page-in-wordpress/) :

```
//* List child pages [jla_childpages]
function jla_list_child_pages() {
  global $post;
    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )
      $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
    else
      $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );
    if ( $childpages ) {
      $string = '<ul id="childpages-menu">' . $childpages . '</ul>';
    }
  return $string;
}
add_shortcode('jla_childpages', 'jla_list_child_pages');
```

Anyone has an idea how I can transform this to add parent page to be the list first item whenever the list is shown ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would add something like

```
//* List child pages [jla_childpages]
function jla_list_child_pages() {
  global $post;

    $parentID = ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID;
    $parentPost = get_post($parentID);
    $isParentCurrent = (get_the_ID() == $parentID) ? " current_page_item" : '';

    $parent = "<li class='page_item page-item-{$parentID}{$isParentCurrent}'><a href='".get_permalink( $parentID )."'>{$parentPost->post_title}</a></li>";

    $childpages = wp_list_pages( "sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of={$parentID}&echo=0" );

    if ( $childpages )
      return '<ul id="childpages-menu">' . $parent . $childpages . '</ul>';

}
add_shortcode('jla_childpages', 'jla_list_child_pages');
```

I haven't tested it, but all you're doing is figuring out the parent before everything, and including the parent above the children in the return.